# How much a Flash memory of an MPC can be flashed/erased (Flash Endurance , life cycles)

Tags: microcontroller, erase, flash-memory, mpc

I began  programming the MCP5748G, the problem  is that i'm working on an existing application and I'm adding a module that depends on other modules.

The module i'm developing is working well but when combined with the others modules both have to be modified. So for this purpose i'm doing a lot of debugging and re-programming of the flash memory.
Sometimes i could go up to **100 flash/erase cycles per day**.

The developpement should take a while let's say 2 month and i don't know if the MCU can resist this period.

That's why i'm wondering for

***What is the maximum of flash cycles for this MCU ?***  : the documentation is too long and i couldn't find the information on it.

And also i'm flashing and erasing just a specified blocks of the flash memory.The total flash is 5mb but i'm using 2mb only. I flash per blocks of 256kb , ***i want to know if flashing just a block affects the other blocks too and also if the performance of the flash memory is degrading after each erase/flash operation.***

I know that every MCU support different flash cycles but if you have some infos on how to find the answer on the doc it would be very helpfull too.

Thanks

Comment: so you expect us to read the documentation because you dont want to?  technologies and implementations vary so there is no universal answer you have to look up the answer for that part.  instead of asking stackoverflow ask the chip vendor they have people there for those kinds of questions.

Comment: @dwelch i have never said that :p i'm asking on how to look for it ... i have searched for 'endurance' and 'life cycles' but i didn't found anything helpfull

Comment: you looked for single words like flash, cycles, erase in the documentation?

Comment: and you contacted the chip vendor's support?

Comment: @dwelch contacting the chip's vendor could be my latest solution since i'm in north africa and i don't know how much that will cost $.... yes the problem is that i couldn't find any info on that i have tried all keywords related to the topic ... i found just the flash paging ,adresses, flash controller very detailed but there is nothing said about flash cycles wich i've found weird for such an important info ... i'm also not a englishman so i havn't found the right sentence to search in google too ... thanks

Comment: support looks to be free and online...for a question like this that is where you start not end.

Comment: i found that their site is not very active so the reason of posting here but i'll try  let you know thanks

Comment: it took me only a few minutes to figure out what company and what chip since you got a couple of letters backward, then within a very small fraction of a second to find the section in the datasheet that talks about flash erase cycles/retention.

Comment: get the datasheet and search for the word erase.

Comment: @dwelch i have already the datasheet and i've found what you mean ... so for 10 years flash life i can go up to 250 000 flash/erase that's about 7 years of flashing 100 times per day =D good. However in Flash memory module life specifications we have a min value (1000) and a typical value (250000) do you know what the min value represent in this case .. thanks for your help i have to search more next time

Comment: @dwelch the next question would be the life expectency of the JTAG DEBUGGER by LAUTERBACH ,how much it can flash / erase .. i don't know if it will survice like the MPC but i will search for it

Comment: to be honest i've found the graph that shows the life cycles ... but i haven't know if it's the right information since i haven't know what data retention and also i was expecting a single value for flash / erase cycles ... but it seems that they depends on the number of years it will work well

Comment: the debugger doesnt wear out it is just a tool to program the target (mcu flash I assume is what you are asking).